# (gTest) calling mocked method from within the same class is not recognized by EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to create helper callable object, that will be used instead of functor in callback registration function. I want to check if callback was invoked when value changed and if it holds correct value. Problem is that even when object is invoked, test dont recognize function call and say that function was not called.

```
template <typename T>
class CallbackFunctionMock
{
public:
    CallbackFunctionMock()          = default;
    virtual ~CallbackFunctionMock() = default;
    CallbackFunctionMock(const CallbackFunctionMock&)                   {};
    CallbackFunctionMock& operator=(const CallbackFunctionMock& other)  { return *this; }


    MOCK_METHOD1_T(MockFunctor, void(T));

    void operator()(T newValue)
    {
        std::cout << "------------------------------input value: " << newValue << std::endl;   
        std::cout << "------------------------------beforeCallback" << std::endl;
        MockFunctor(newValue);
        std::cout << "------------------------------afterCallback" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Test looks like this:

```
TEST_F(SpecificDeviceTest, TestName)
{
    CallbackFunctionMock<const int&> helper;
    m_specificDevice->SubscribeCallback(helper);
    std::cout << "------------------------------11111111111111111111111" << std::endl;
    EXPECT_CALL(helper, MockFunctor(10)).Times(1);
    std::cout << "------------------------------22222222222222222222222" << std::endl;
    m_specificDevice->UpdateValue(10); 
    std::cout << "------------------------------33333333333333333333333" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using template version, because we have multiple devices and all of them use different type.

Output after building project shows:

```
1>[ RUN      ] SpecificDeviceTest.TestName
1>------------------------------11111111111111111111111
1>------------------------------22222222222222222222222
1>------------------------------input value: 10
1>------------------------------beforeCallback
1>------------------------------afterCallback
1>------------------------------33333333333333333333333
1>c:\path\to\some\tests\SpecificDeviceTest.cpp: error : Actual function call         
count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(helper, MockFunctor(10))...
1>         Expected: to be called once
1>           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
1>[  FAILED  ] SpecificDeviceTest.TestName(1 ms)
```

EDIT1:
@S.M m_specific device is our class that represent real element. 
Definition for SubscribeCallback and UpdateState is as follow:

```
void Device::SubscribeCallback( boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>::slot_type clbk)
{
       valueChangedSignal.connect(clbk);
}

auto Device::UpdateValue(const int& newValue) -> void
{
        valueChangedSignal(newValue);
}
```

and valueChangedSignal is member deklared as:

```
boost::signals2::signal<void(int)> valueChangedSignal;
```

EDIT2: Turns out there is faster and easier solution using MockFunction, which does not require additional objects:

```
TEST_F(SpecificDeviceTest, TestName)
{
    MockFunction<void(const int&)> mock_function;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_function, Call(10)).Times(1);

    m_specificDevice->SubscribeCallback(mock_function.AsStdFunction());
    m_specificDevice->UpdateValue(10); 
}
```

Comment: What is`m_specificDevice`. Maybe it copied the helper.

Comment: @S.M. i have eddited question and added function definition, are there problems with copying objects and calling methods ?

Comment: Sure it is a problem. MockFunctor of the copied object is called, but the test expects MockFunctor of the original object is called.